# Reading a csv file in to Python

Tags: python

I am trying to read a csv file using Python. But I get the following error

```
utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xa3 in position 28: invalid start byte
```

One of the column in my Dataset is a string one. However some of them in this column are treated **as number** and some other **as string**

Please help me....

Comment: Can you give an example of your code and file?

Comment: https://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html or https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_csv.html and please post your code ...

Answer (score 1):

I was also having the same error. Try the below code:

```
import csv
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv('nameOfYourFile.csv',encoding='utf-16')
print(df.columns)
```